# Can two electrons co-moving in a vacuum form a combined pair if the magnetic field is stronger than the electric field?

Tags: electrons

Can two electrons co-moving in a vacuum form a combined pair if the magnetic field is stronger than the electric field?  Quantum numbers are same except for magnetic value.

When electrons are first emitted they are probably moving at near light speed.
When electrons are in atomic orbits they are assumed to move at near light speed.
If the velocity was well below light speed, can the magnetic field of the two electrons allow them to combine.

Comment: What you mean by "form combined pair" ? There are mechanisms where pair of electrons can be bound together, for example [Cooper pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair) in superconductors, but this bounding of electrons doesn't required any magnetic field, just electron-phonon interaction. So to say cooper pairs avoids scattering from phonons better (or none at all).

Comment: co-moving means that they are moving with the same velocity close to each other? If so  at the center of mass of the two electrons they are both at rest. The coulomb repulsion will not allow them to bond.

Comment: In the rest frame of the two electrons there is no magnetic field. So two comoving electrons will always repel each other.

Comment: You might be interested in magnetically insulated transmission lines, where the magnetic field from the high current confines the current.

Answer (score 1):

Two co-moving electrons exert a repulsive electric force and an attractive magnetic force. So it would seem that at some great speed the attractive magnetic force should be equal to the repulsive electric force. Then at even higher speeds the magnetic attraction would be greater than the electric repulsion and the electrons could form a bound system of some sort.

It is a worthwhile exercise to calculate what that speed is. It turns out that the critical speed is $c$, the speed of light. This speed is impossible to achieve. So a pair of electrons will never form a bound system in the sense asked.